# Display random line from .txt file - c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to do something in c# (winforms) but i'm stuck on a small problem. I've tried all codes related to this problem but without success. Please read the problem before answering.

I have 2 functions. I want to make 1 function which will get a random line from specific .txt file and put it in the other one.

Here is an example of that:

```
//This is a ContexMenuStrip, a right click menu item that need to load Function1 (check the picture below

private void pdkName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Function1();
}

private void Function1()
{
      //CODE to Count and Display random line from .txt file
}
```

So far i've tried many codes that were previously posted here on stackoverflow.com and i've also tried tons of combinations with them. I will paste some of them here:

---

```
Random rand = new Random();
IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\FirstName.txt");
var lineToRead = rand.Next(1, lines.Count());
var line = lines.Skip(lineToRead - 1).First();
```

---

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file =
    new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\FirstNames.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(line);
    counter++;
}
file.Close();
System.Console.WriteLine("There were {0} lines.", counter);
// Suspend the screen.
System.Console.ReadLine();
```

---

// This worked but only for the first line, can't do any combination with it (from the other functions to make it random)

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"D:\FirstName.txt")
{
   textBox1.Text = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

---

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\FirstNames.txt");
var r = new Random();
var randomLineNumber = r.Next(0, lines.Length - 1);
var line = lines[randomLineNumber];
```

---

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\FirstNames.txt"); 
Random rand = new Random();
return lines[rand.Next(lines.Length)];
```

---

The function needs to count the file, pick a random line and return it. The item menu from the ContexMenuStrip that calls the function is used on a TEXTBOX.

So in general, i need a random name from the .txt file to be shown inside a textbox with clicking the right click on the textbox and selecting the item which loads my function. Here is a little picture with simple explanation.

[image]

Comment: The first approach with `FileReadLines` fails because [`FileReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) uses a `TextReader` internally which dispose as soon as you execute the query. That happens at `lines.Count()`, so the next access throws  an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: I don't understand your question well. You want to get a line from a Text file randomly without duplicate or not? I mean that suppose the Text file has 4 lines: `Line 1, Line 2, Line 3, Line 4`, the first time you get a line randomly which is `Line 2`, the second time may you get the same line `Line 2`? and so on...

Comment: It doesn't matter, the .txt file is a huge base with names. Let's say it has 1000 names, the code needs to pick 1 random name every time the function is called.

Comment: If there are only 1000 names it would be better to load it into memory at the beginig instead of opening the file and searching it again everytime you want to display the name. Or at least count lines at the beining to have bounds for random generation.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness. Does my solution work for you too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like fabian said or declare random inside the square brackets and directly calling the method next

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\...\....\YourFile.txt");

textBox1.Text = lines[new Random().Next(lines.Length)];
```

Comment: The upper bound of `Random.Next` is exclusive, and `0` is implicit.

Comment: This worked just fine, thanks everybody especially terrybozzio!

Answer (score 1):

define your random as a private member in your form:

```
private _rand = new Random();
```

Then in your Event from the ContextMenuStrip, paste this code (Make sure to edit the filename "yourFile.txt"):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\FirstNames.txt");
var randomLineNumber = _rand.Next(0, lines.Length - 1);
var line = lines[randomLineNumber]; //getting the random line
using (StreamWriter sw= File.AppendText("yourFile.txt")) 
{
     sw.WriteLine(line); //append the random line in your file
}
```

Comment: The upper bound of `Random.Next` is exclusive, and `0` is implicit.